# XML Adding attribute to the wrong node

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, domxpath

I'm new to xml and I can't figure out how to set the *rate* attribute for the *code* node. For some reason it sets the attribute to the *currency* node.

```
<?

@date_default_timezone_set("GMT"); 
if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $xml=new DomDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
    $xml->formatOutput=true;
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace=false;
    $xml->load('rates.xml');

    $curcode = $_POST['currency-code'];
    $newrate = $_POST['rate'];

    $change = new DOMXpath($xml);

    $update = $change->query("//*[code = '$curcode']");
    $update->item(0)->setAttribute("rate", $newrate);
    $xml->save('rates.xml');
}
?>
```

Here is the xml:

```
<currencies>
  <currency>
    <code rate="18.543343372942">ZAR</code>
    <cname>Rand</cname>
    <cntry>Lesotho, Namibia, South Africa</cntry>
  </currency>
  <currency>
    <code rate="123">test</code>
    <cname>ewwwwwww</cname>
    <cntry>rew</cntry>
  </currency>
  <currency rate="432432434332432">
    <code rate="1234">testnew</code>
    <cname>nene</cname>
    <cntry>fnnfr</cntry>
  </currency>
</currencies>
```

As you can see, on the last one *currency* node, the *currency rate* is being updated instead of the *code rate*.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath query returns element `<currency>`.
Because `//*[code = '$curcode']` selects all elements that have `code` element with value of `$curcode`.

So all you need is just to select `code` element. Like this:

```
$update = $change->query("//*[code = '$curcode']/code");
```

or

```
$update = $change->query("//code[text() = '$curcode']");
```